# Powershell Rename-Item repeats if the number of files is large

Tags: windows-10, powershell, filesystems, file-management

(I'm just going to post every path here. It feels awkwardly intimate but what harm could it possibly do, right?)

Here is my PowerShell command prompt:

```
PS D:\Local generations\Tlungvel> ls | Rename-Item -NewName {"TlungvelSolar " + $_.Name}
Rename-Item : Could not find a part of the path.
At line:1 char:6
+ ls | Rename-Item -NewName {"TlungvelSolar " + $_.Name}
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\Local genera..._02.07.2021.xls:String) [Rename-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Rename-Item : Could not find a part of the path.
At line:1 char:6
+ ls | Rename-Item -NewName {"TlungvelSolar " + $_.Name}
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\Local genera..._23.07.2021.xls:String) [Rename-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

... and so on it goes for every file in the directory.

The command seem simple enough even for a beginner poweruser like me ("ls | Rename-Item -NewName {"TlungvelSolar " + $_.Name}") and it works fine if the number of files in the directory is small. But if the number of files reach a certain threshold the process just repeats itself indefinitely and throws itself into the above error for each file.

For example, one of the filenames is "Power_Drawal_from_23.07.2021___24.07.2021"

If the file count crosses 22 (for this filename) it renames it to "TlungvelSolar TlungvelSolar TlungvelSolar TlungvelSolar TlungvelSolar TlungvelSolar TlungvelSolar TlungvelSolar TlungvelSolar TlungvelSolar TlungvelSolar TlungvelSolar TlungvelSolar Power_Drawal_from_23.07.2021___24.07.2021" (the number of repetition is as limited by the Windows' maximum 256 character file path limit).

Now what I want it to rename it to is "TlungvelSolar Power_Drawal_from_23.07.2021___24.07.2021"

Again, it works fine if the number of files is less, and it also seem to depend on the filenames.

Comment: Try: `ls | ForEach-Object {$_ | Rename-Item -NewName {"TlungvelSolar " + $_.Name}}`.

Comment: Same result. I forgot to mention that the issue does not affect sub-folders. In other words sub-folders are renamed just they way I intend.

Comment: An enigmatic pipeline… Try starting from a static file list as follows: `$aux=Get-Childitem; $aux | Rename-Item -NewName {"TlungvelSolar " + $_.Name}`

Comment: Yas!! @JosefZ thank you. Can you expound on the problem a little bit? Out of curiosity.

Comment: your problem is caused by feeding items to the pipeline **_while changing the source_**. [*grin*] ///// the fix is something like one of the following -- **_[A]_** grab all the items into a $Var and feed that into your pipeline. **_[B]_** wrap the `G-CI` call in parens to force it to read all the items ONE TIME. **_[C]_** use a `foreach` loop instead of the pipeline.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey You should post that as answer because it is a very common 'gotcha' when changing anything from a file while iterating through the pipeline. Your answer may help quite a few people I think.

Comment: @Theo - done! thank you for pointing that out. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is caused by feeding items into the pipeline ***while changing the source.*** [*grin*] that makes it quite easy to re-process the same item - it LOOKS like a different item to the code.

the fix is something like one of the below solutions ...

- grab all the items into a $Var and feed that *complete collection* into the pipeline
- wrap the `G-CI` call in parens to force the call to grab everything *one time*
- use a `foreach` loop

i prefer the 3rd of those since it makes for a much simpler, more obvious set of steps ... and thus easier to debug. [*grin*]